# Why do GWTRPC *Service Interface classes go in ".client" package instead of ".shared"?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

Looking at the GWT sample apps and the [RPC tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) the following package conventions are used:

```
./client/GreetingService.java
./client/GreetingServiceAsync.java
./server/GreetingServiceImpl.java
```

Though the GWT docs are very sparse on best-practices what components get included where at runtime, the clear intuition is:

- client - Compiled into JavaScript by GWT compiler
- server - Compiled into bytecode by javac
- shared - Compiled into JavaScript by GWT compiler **and** compiled into bytecode by javac

This would lead one to believe that code in `client` should **not** be on the compile-time sourcepath of javac.  Yet since `GreetingServiceImpl` implements `GreetingService`, clearly code in `client` needs to be on the sourcepath during compilation, and included on the runtime classpath at deployment.

Given this, why doesn't the `GreetingService` interface go in `shared`?

If you try to put it in `shared`, the [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_rpc.html) complains "Missing Asynchronous Interface"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to be clear :

- There is no **technical** difference between the **client** and the **shared** package, it's only a matter of convention. Both are declared as source packages in your module (the **.gwt.xml** file)
- **client** and **shared** package get both compiled into **javascript** and **bytecode**
- On **server** side, the bytecode for the whole client part is usually available, although most of it is **not used**.
- Therefore, some people just remove the **shared** package, and put everything in the **client** package. It's a matter of taste.
- As Thomas said, the `Service` interface must be available to your client code. So it must either be in the **client** package or the **shared** package. But the `ServiceAsync` interface must be in the same package as the `Service` interface. And the `ServiceAsync` is certainly not something that is considered shared between **client** and **server**. So the `ServiceASync` interface should be in the **client** package.
- As a consequence, the `Service` interface is put in the **client** package.
- In your case, the **GWT Eclipse Plugin** complained because the `ServiceASync` interface was not found in the `Service` interface package.
- You can still use the **shared** package for the classes that are sent through **RPC**.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Though given this explanation, I don't really see any useful conventions for what goes in the `shared` package.  It would seem that RPC transfer objects would just as well go in `client` alongside the interfaces that use them.  Perhaps the best convention for `shared` is for code that has legitimate server side uses even in the absence of a client.

Comment: Also - do you have a reference to the GWT documentation that states the above?  In particular the first 3 bullet points?

Comment: See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules for the first 2 bullet points. For the third one, well, it's only a matter of how you build up your classpath. In my projects, my `client` code is *not* deployed on the server-side, only the `shared` one (I usually use 3 projects: `shared`, `client` and `server`; `client` and `server` depending on `shared`; I put `client` and `shared` in the classpath for the GWT DevMode and Compiler, and I deploy `shared` and `server` on the server; works best for medium/big projects)

Comment: I guess that with Thomas details, you now have all the needed information ;-)

Comment: @Thomas - Do you deploy your GWTRPC services all in `shared` then?  If so, that would conflict with Piwai's 5th point (...So the `ServiceAsync` interface should be in the client package.)

Comment: Yes. I'd rather have a "non-shared" interface in `shared` than server-side code reference `client`.

Answer (score 1):

In my projects both `Service` and `ServiceAsync` are in `shared` and everything works ok. Actually I don't see it any other way as `SercviceImpl` in `server` implements `Service` interface and compiler needs to have them on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

GWT-RPC generator uses a naming convention (sticking an `Async` suffix to the classname), adding a "package renaming rule" (`Service` in `shared` while `ServiceAsync` is in `client`) would like not fit with many people's package layout. So, the rule is that both interfaces are in the same package, whichever the name of the package, which allows you to put them in `shared` if you want (as Peter Knego said)

(that rule is also due to legacy, the `shared` convention has been introduced in GWT projects quite recently, comparatively with GWT-RPC)

Comment: `Service` cannot go into `server` since it appears in the argument to the `GWT.create(Service.class)` call.